# How to copy a pandas styler to the clipboard

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on an automated text generator.
I would like to know is is it possible somehow to copy a pandas styler table to the clipboard.

So far:

```
import pandas as pd
text="some text I want to print also"
df = pd.read_excel('sample.xls')
table=df.style.set_properties(**{'border':'1px solid black'})
```

For the text I use pyperclip to copy to clipboard.
For me the ideal would be to print my text and the styled table to the clipboard together.

This is how my data frame looks like:

```
      Sample     Gender    QC   Note      GC(%)   Mass_result(%)  Mappedreads    Dup
0  20D8406235P1  Female  PASS   NaN       47.810       NaN           99.83       28.66
```

Is it possible to make it?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you please be more concret, where you want to past the code later? A [`styler`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html) has 3 export options: [`to_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html#More-About-CSS-and-HTML), `to_latex()` and `to_excel()`. Maybe one of this existing solutions is what you are looking for.

Comment: why do you want to copy it to the clipboard? this is probably not the best solution

Comment: I Would like to save it to clipboard (like ctrl+c) to just ctrl+v where I want the text.

I want it this way, because I have to insert a table to an outlook email, and I have to make it by hand, and I have to make it pretty often.